# why the "up" button moves me to the main activity and not to the parent activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an application with three activities.

MainActivity which looks like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("click me to go to child activity");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class));
            }
        });
        setContentView(b);
    }
}
```

ChildActivity which looks like that:

```
public class ChildActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TextView(this) {{
            setText("I'm the child activity");
        }});
    }
}
```

And OtherActivity which looks like that:

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TextView(this) {{
            setText("I'm other activity");
        }});
    }
}
```

In the manifest I have such declaration:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="pl.psobolewski.test.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="pl.psobolewski.test.ChildActivity" />
    <activity android:name="pl.psobolewski.test.OtherActivity" />
</application>
```

Now when I start the application, it starts with MainActivity, from there I can go to ChildActivity, but there is no way to go to OtherActivity.

Then in the manifest I change this line:

```
<activity android:name="pl.psobolewski.test.ChildActivity" />
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="pl.psobolewski.test.ChildActivity" android:parentActivityName="pl.psobolewski.test.OtherActivity" />
```

Now I start again this application on my phone, which has Android API 16. It starts with MainActivity, there I can press the button and move to ChildActivity. Now the ChildActivity looks a little bit different than before: the logo on ActionBar has a little arrow-like icon (documentation calls it "a left-facing caret") which means it can be used to move up. But when I press it I don't go to OtherActivity - even though it is declared as the parent of ChildActivity - but to the MainActivity.

I find it contrary with the Android documentation which says:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html
"android:parentActivityName
The system reads this attribute to determine which activity should be started when the use presses the Up button in the action bar. The system can also use this information to synthesize a back stack of activities with TaskStackBuilder."

I also thought that adding android:parentActivityName attribute without calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled would not turn the application logo into the up button - the documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html suggests so.

My question is: why the "up" button moves me to the MainActivity and not to the OtherActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Action Bar up navigation handler has been implemented in such a way that if the parent of current activity has no parent, then an Intent is created with ACTION_MAIN & CATEGORY_LAUNCHER to start the activity. This results in MainActivity being launched.
Have a look at definition of getParentActivityIntent() in [Activity.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

To overcome this, in your ChildActivity.java override below 2 methods of Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(Intent intent) {
    return true; // This creates a new task stack
}

@Override
public Intent getParentActivityIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    return intent;
}
```

If you don't want to override getParentActivityIntent, then you need to define a parent activity for OtherActivity in AndroidManifest.xml file, to overcome the earlier mentioned reason.

If you don't override shouldUpRecreateTask, since OtherActivity does not appear in history stack, it will remove all activities until the root activity of the task is reached, resulting in 'in-app home' behavior.

Comment: Did you try the solution?